# How to create an android 10 VM and have it communicate with my Ubuntu VM?

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox

I need to setup an android 10 VM on virtual box (so it can communicate with my ubuntu VM), but I couldn't find anything above version 9.0 on https://www.android-x86.org/download .
I thought I'd get it from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-29_r08-windows.zip , which is the link used by android studio for installing an android 10 emulator.I expected it to be an .iso image, but it's actually a folder with muliple files in it, and no iso file.
Do you know any other way ? Or an alternative solution to creating a virtualbox vm ? Is there any way to have the android studio emulator communicate with my ubuntu VM for example ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android 10 Emulator in the Android Studio IDE to create an Android 10 virtual machine (VM). You can then use the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) to connect the VM to your Ubuntu VM and transfer data between them.

Or

First, you need to create an Ubuntu VM. You can do this using VirtualBox or another virtualization tool.

Once you have created the VM, you will need to install the Android SDK on it. You can do this by following the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once the Android SDK is installed, you will need to create an AVD (Android Virtual Device) for your VM. You can do this by following the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/manage-avds.html

Once you have created the AVD, you can boot it up and it should appear in your VM. You can then access it from your Ubuntu VM using the adb tool.

Comment: Thank you ! I am trying your first solution, but I can't get adb to connect to my android VM from ubuntu. `adb devices ` shows my emulator with the "attached" value set as "device" (which I don't know how to interpret), and I have run the `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555` in the adb shell without error. When I try `adb connect 10.0.2.15` on my ubuntu VM, it says the network is unreachable. I have my virtual box network setting on private host only. Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?